# At what non-preclearance airports are there US DHS officers?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports, officials

I've read that at certain airports (especially London airports), there are sometimes American DHS officers doing spot checks of passengers about to board flights to the US.

At what airports is this the case?

Comment: Read *where*? I find it hard to credit this given that DHS has *zero* authority in the UK.

Comment: @Paulie_D A few sources https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/middle-east/topics/travelling-to-usa-with-republic-of-iraq-erbil-visa-stamp-in-passport?page=2 https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destinations/north-america/united-states/articles/Travel-to-the-US-how-to-get-in-and-your-rights-if-youre-denied-entry/

Comment: Hmmm, I only see one reference to DHS and that's apocryphal

Comment: While a DHS officer would have no authority in the UK without some special agreements (which exist at preclearance airports), it is conceivable that DHS officials are occasionally given permission to make enquiries in UK airports. That would make sense if, for example, there was a known threat against a US target.

Comment: Take a look at this [DHS info](https://www.dhs.gov/aviation-security) which speaks of enhanced security measures at 280 last-point-of-departure airports (in 105 countries) with direct flights to the US (and includes passenger screening). The carrier would have to comply, and that may be what occurred.

Comment: @Paulie_D The US Government does have authority over US registered (flagged) aircraft worldwide. The FAA will show up and conduct a safety inspection/ride-along worldwide. Second, the US Government does have authority to deny any aircraft access to its airspace. If a carrier doesn't comply with DHS (or FAA) procedures and inspections, the plane will be turned away at the border.

Comment: None of this confirms that there are DHS agents carrying out such checks. Even the confirmed denial / ESTA cancellation was made by UK Border Security based on a **phone call** from the US Government. This does not pass the sniff test.

Comment: @Giorgio Specifically your link does NOT say that DHS officers carry out any of the precautions at last-point-of-departure airports.

Comment: @Paulie_D what makes you think it was UK border security?  If you're referring to the lonely planet link, the traveler says "he told me he was home land security," so it seems that it was a US officer.

Comment: @Giorgio that link is about physical security screening, not immigration screening: "passengers flying to the United States may experience additional screening of their person, property, and electronic devices."

Comment: @DJClayworth they can and do, apparently, even where there are not pre-clearance facilities, e.g., coverage in this NYTimes article last year, [Homeland Security Goes Abroad. Not Everyone Is Grateful.](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/26/world/americas/homeland-security-customs-border-patrol.html)

Comment: In many (most?) cases of flights to the US, there are additional checks performed at the gate. This is usually performed by private companies, but there's probably no reason it could not be done by DHS representatives, though their authority would not be greater than that of a private security firm. But they could indeed prevent someone from boarding.

Comment: @jcaron they do not literally prevent people from boarding; they just recommend to the airline not to board the passenger.  The end effect is the same, but it is less problematic from a legal point of view.

Comment: @phoog I'm pretty sure the "recommendation" can be quite strong, like "if you don't follow our recommendations then we won't allow the flight to enter US airspace". But of course they probably don't directly prevent the passenger from boarding themselves.

Comment: @jcaron unlikely.  It seems rather that it is no stronger than "if you don't follow our recommendation then we'll fine you at the standard rate when we deny entry to this passenger.  But that's plenty strong to prevent the airline from boarding the passenger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [Immigration Advisory Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_Advisory_Program).  The Customs and Border Protection (CBP) [fact sheet](https://www.cbp.gov/document/fact-sheets/immigration-advisory-program-iap) does not name the airports at which it is in effect.

According to an EU [document](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1540493240896&uri=CELEX:52013SC0630), in 2013 the program comprised 11 airports in 9 countries.  CBP does publish [a list of embassies where it has posted attachés](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/international-initiatives/cbp-attaches), but this currently comprises 24 countries, and the scope of the attachés' duties is rather wider than just the IAP.  It is probably safe to say, however, that airports outside of those countries are not in the program.

There is also a somewhat meager page on [international engagement](https://www.dhs.gov/topic/international-engagement) at CBP's parent department, the Department of Homeland Security.

The Government Accountability Office published a [report](https://www.gao.gov/products/GAO-17-216) in 2017 that identifies the airports in the IAP and the related Joint Security Program (JSP).  They are

IAP:

- Manchester, UK
- London Heathrow, UK
- London Gatwick, UK
- Amsterdam, Netherlands
- Frankfurt, Germany
- Paris (airport not identified), France
- Madrid, Spain
- Doha, Qatar
- Tokyo, Japan

JSP:

- Mexico City, Mexico
- Panama City, Panama

Since that seems to be eleven airports in nine countries, it is possible that the EU document may have considered the two programs together.  The description of the program officers' authority is germane to some of the comments on the question:

> Immigration Advisory Program (IAP) and Joint Security Program (JSP). IAP and JSP operate at foreign airports. According to CBP officials, under this program, unarmed, plain clothes CBP officers posted at foreign airports partner with air carriers and host country government officials to help prevent terrorists and other high-risk individuals from boarding U.S.-bound flights by vetting and interviewing them before
>   travel.<sup>19</sup>
>   According to CBP program documentation, CBP established IAP in 2004 to prevent terrorists, high-risk, and improperly documented travelers from boarding airlines destined to the United States. Building on the IAP concept, CBP established JSP in 2009 to partner with host country law enforcement officials to identify high-risk travelers. CBP officers at IAP and JSP locations have the ability to question travelers and review their travel documents. They are to act in an advisory manner to the air carriers and host governments and do not have authority to deny boarding to individuals on U.S.-bound flights or fully inspect travelers or their belongings. IAP and JSP officers are authorized by CBP to make recommendations to airlines as to whether to board or deny boarding (known as a no-board recommendation) to selected travelers based on their likely admissibility status upon arrival to the United States. The final decision to board travelers, however, lies with the carriers.

Footnote 19 is a reference to [8 USC 1225a(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1225A#b), which mandates immigration preinspection at foreign airports.